# Compare two files without altering the length of the file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, compare

I would to compare this two files:

File 1

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

File 2

```
b
c
e
```

And the expected output

```
a x
b o
c o
d x
e o
```

In conclusion I want a output to tell if the line in the file 2 is in the file 2 but without altering the length of file 1

Comment: have you tried `diff`? It's unclear exactly what you need, since how do you know whether the second line should compare "b" with "b" or "c"?

Comment: or `man comm`? You can probably post-process that output more easily. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: `comm` is a great tool, but requires its input to be sorted.  Granted, the sample data is in sorted order, but that should be noted.  — Oh, I just did note it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Noted and agreed ;-). The reference to `comm` was to help an obvious new user be aware of other options available. Thanks for mentioning the sorted constraint, I should have done that.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a go for unix diff utility:

```
diff -u file1 file2 > file3
```

The output expected is not exactly what you are looking for but it is also readable and it does not alter the size of file 1.